# Matplotlib is making positives into negatives

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm just trying to graph some simple data and whether I try to do it with plot or subplot it comes out the same. All values in my lists are positive but the y axis is acting like a number line with only positives.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xVal = []
yVal1 = []
yVal2 = []
yVal3 = []
data = []

# load data
with open(r"path", 'r') as f:
data = f.readlines()

yVal1 = data[0].split(",")
yVal2 = data[1].split(",")
yVal3 = data[2].split(",")

del yVal1[-1]
del yVal2[-1]
del yVal3[-1]

print(yVal1)
print(yVal2)
print(yVal3)

# graph dem bois
xVal = [*range(0, len(yVal1))]

'''fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)

ax[0].plot(xVal, yVal1)
ax[0].set_title("pm5")

ax[1].plot(xVal, yVal2)
ax[1].set_title("pm7.5")

ax[2].plot(xVal, yVal3)
ax[2].set_title("pm10")

fig.suptitle("Particulate Levels over time")'''

plt.plot(xVal, yVal3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: convert y-vals from strings to floats.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thank you! I cannot believe I overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment by Jody Klymak I converted the string lists into float lists and it worked.

```
fyVal1 = [float(x) for x in yVal1]
```